# CodeIgniter, pass data from model to controller to display sql operations results in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my **Login controller**

```
 <?php if (! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Login extends CI_Controller
    {

        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();

        }

        public function index($msg = NULL)
        {
            $this->load->helper('url');
            // Load the model
            $this->load->model('login_model');
            // Validate the user can login
            $this->login_model->loginAction();      
        }   
    }
    ?>
```

And my Model **Login_model** is

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login_model extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }

    public function loginAction()
    {
        // grab user input
        $email = $this->input->get('email');
        $password = $this->input->get('password');

        // Prep the query
        $this->db->where('email', $email);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);

        // Run the query
        $query = $this->db->get('users');

        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $dbid= $row->id;
            $dbemail= $row->email;
        }

        $value=$query->num_rows();
        if($value == 1)
        {
            $details = array(
            'status'=>'sucess', 
            'message'=>'sucessfully logedin ',

            'id' => $dbid,
            'email' => $dbemail, 
            );
            echo  json_encode($details);
        }
        else
        {
            $detail = array(
            'status'=>'failed', 
            'message'=>'invalid email password ',

            );
            echo  json_encode($detail);
            return false;
        }
    }   
}
?>
```

This is working, but I need to use  **$details** & **$detail** arrays in my **Login controller** to encode json data. for that what all modifications that I need to put in both my model and controller. I am new to codeIgniter.

Comment: $variablename = $this->login_model->loginAction();

print_r($variablename);
die;

Comment: and in model where u echo here just return only variable and encoded in controller

Comment: Password over get method? o.O

Comment: it just for api development

Answer (score 0):

Make changes as below

```
 <?php if (! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Login extends CI_Controller
    {

        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();

        }

        public function index($msg = NULL)
        {
              $this->load->helper('url');
            // Load the model
            $this->load->model('login_model');
            // Validate the user can login
            $result = $this->login_model->loginAction();
            if($result['status'])
            {
               $details = array(
                           'status'=>'sucess', 
                           'message'=>'sucessfully logedin ',

                           'id' => $result['data']->id,
                           'email' => $result['data']->email, 
                          );
             }else{
                       $detail = array(
                             'status'=>'failed', 
                             'message'=>'invalid email password '
                     );

             }
             echo  json_encode($detail);
        }   
    }
    ?>
```

And my Model **Login_model** is

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login_model extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }

    public function loginAction()
    {
        // grab user input
        $email = $this->input->get('email');
        $password = $this->input->get('password');

        // Prep the query
        $this->db->where('email', $email);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);

        // Run the query
        $query = $this->db->get('users');

        $value=$query->num_rows();
        if($value == 1)
        {
            return ['status'=>true, 'data'=>$query->row_object()];
        }
        else
        {
            return ['status'=>false];
        }
    }   
}
?>
```